Prometheus - how to group by lable 2 metrics and filter one with another?
I have 2 metrics:
levels{set_id, instance_id}
levels_expected{set_id}

I need to group both by set_id and count all sets, where all instance_id values of levels equals levels_expected value.
Ex.:
levels{set_id=1, instance_id=1} = 1
levels{set_id=1, instance_id=2} = 2
levels_expected{set_id= 1} = 2

levels{set_id=2, instance_id=1} = 2
levels{set_id=2, instance_id=2} = 2
levels_expected{set_id = 2} = 2

levels{set_id=3, instance_id=1} = 2
levels{set_id=3, instance_id=2} = 1
levels_expected{set_id = 3} = 2

levels{set_id=4, instance_id=1} = 2
levels{set_id=4, instance_id=2} = 2
levels_expected{set_id = 4} = 2


Should return 2(total sets = 4, leveled sets = 2)

Something like count by(set_id)(levels == on(set_id) levels_expected)?

Not sure. This query seemed to work with one leveled set. When I added another one grafana says "execution: multiple matches for labels: many-to-one matching must be explicit (group_left/group_right)". Query in prometheus works but producing n-values equal to total number of sets and all values is 1, so it is not working.

count( sum by(set_id) (levels != bool on(set_id) group_left() levels_expected) == 0 )
